# Call <Address> Calculation

Tags: c++, assembly, hook

Well, I'm working on a Hook like system, where I want to copy the call instruction (Hex Operation Code) to a certain location, so when that is executed it calls an alien function, but when I assemble 'call 0x100' it comes out as 'E8 FD', but how does it calculate 0x100 into 0xFD? I've heard that this is done by using this equation:

```
((Origin - Destination)/4)/4
```

But, how does it do this if the origin is not know?

Comment: the processor knows the address it is executing the instruction from and applies the offset based on that (and based on the known math for computing the destination for that particular instruction).

Comment: By the way, `e8 fd` is probably not the full instruction. The following byte (in 16-bit mode) or 3 bytes (in 32-bit mode) also belong to the offset.

Answer (score 1):

The origin is the address of the instruction *after* your call instruction. Just like the near-jmp instruction. It is stored as an offset. Note that the call instruction is overloaded. There is a near-call which takes 16 bit relative address and a far-call which takes a 32 bit relative address

```
E8 *cw* - CALL rel16 - Call near, relative, displacement relative to next instruction
E8 *cd* - CALL rel32 - Call near, relative, displacement relative to next instruction
```

Source: Intel instruction set reference.

Comment: Thats not exactly what I was looking for, But thanks anyways.

Comment: For a near relative call (opcode 0xe8), the address where control will be transferred by the call is calculated as follows: `<dest_address> = <address_of_the_next_insn> + <offset>`. The address of the next insn is, obviously, <address_of_the_call_insn> + <length_of_the_call_insn>. Now assume you copy that call instruction to a location at address <new_addr> and would like the call to refer to the same function as before. You need to set the offset in the copy as follows: `<dest_address> - (<new_addr> + <length_of_the_call_insn>)`